# Set field values in 1 place and apply those values on all other pages

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF for an ad. There are 2 fields, an image for the ad and the link where the image will lead to if clicked on. I have set them up and they are working correctly. They are required to show on the home page, and on post pages.

Now what this question is about: I would like to be able to set the ad only on the home page (or somewhere else if you have a better idea), and to apply those field values on the post pages.

Currently I set it for the home page, its ok and it works. But if I create a new blog post, I need to select the ad for every new blog post. I believe this is bad UX, because if there is only 1 ad, it would be nicer to set it once and apply it everywhere else.

What would be the best approach to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The true way to do this with ACF is using the $post->ID parameter.

Say you set the value of the field on the homepage, now you wan't to bring it in on other pages the following simply wont work:

```
the_field('homepage_field');
```

You need to tell ACF what page ID to check the value for:

```
the_field('homepage_field', $pageID);
```

If you're trying to get your homepage which is set to front page in the wordpress options use the following:

```
$frontpage_id = (int)get_option( 'page_on_front' );
the_field('homepage_field', $frontpage_id);
```

This will also work with:

- get_field('field_name', $pageID)
- get_sub_field('field_name', $pageID)
- the_sub_field('field_name', $pageID)
- have_rows('field_name', $pageID)

With regards to a potential different option as you mentioned if there is one we would suggest. Try the Premium ACF Options Page plugin, this will allow you to get fields using:

- the_field('field_name', 'options')
- get_field('field_name', 'options')
- get_sub_field('field_name', 'options')
- the_sub_field('field_name', 'options')
- have_rows('field_name', 'options')

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Look at the accepted answer for a cleaner solution

I have done some more research and found a solution.

In your functions.php of your theme, createa a function for the field you want to get. For my situation it looks like this

```
// Get the Sponsored Content Image 
function get_sponsored_content_image()
{
  return get_field('advertisement_photo');
}
```

And then in the template part where you want to access the field just do this:

```
<?php $sponsored_photo = get_sponsored_content_image();
```